# Get MAC address via TCPListener in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, mac-address, tcplistener

Is it possible to get MAC Address of remote client  via TCPListener in C#?

```
using System;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Net.Sockets;  
using System.IO;  
using System.Text;  

namespace TCPserver  
{  
    class Program  
    {  
        private const int BUFSIZE = 32;  

        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            if (args.Length > 1) // Test for correct of args  
                throw new ArgumentException("Parameters: [<Port>]");  

            int servPort = (args.Length == 1) ? Int32.Parse(args[0]) : 7;  

            TcpListener listener = null;  

            try  
            {  
                // Create a TCPListener to accept client connections  
                listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, servPort);  
                listener.Start();  
            }  
            catch (SocketException se)  
            {  
                Console.WriteLine(se.Message);  
                Environment.Exit(se.ErrorCode);  
            }  

            byte[] rcvBuffer = new byte[BUFSIZE]; // Receive buffer  
            int bytesRcvd; // Received byte count  

            for (; ; )  
            { // Run forever, accepting and servicing connections  

                TcpClient client = null;  
                NetworkStream ns = null;  
                try  
                {  
                    client = listener.AcceptTcpClient(); // Get client connection  
                    ns = client.GetStream();  
                    Console.Write("Handling client - ");  

                    // Receive until client closes connection  
                    int totalBytesEchoed = 0;  
                    while ((bytesRcvd = ns.Read(rcvBuffer, 0, rcvBuffer.Length)) > 0)  
                    {  
                        ns.Write(rcvBuffer, 0, bytesRcvd);  
                        totalBytesEchoed += bytesRcvd;  
                    }  
                    Console.WriteLine("echoed {0} bytes.", totalBytesEchoed);  

                    ns.Close();  
                    client.Close();  

                }  
                catch (Exception e)  
                {  
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);  
                    ns.Close();  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: did you look at the ip helper library https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366071(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible based on the fact that a MAC address is a layer 2 (hardware) address and won't be accessible outside the remote device's LAN. On a local network you can do an ARP to get a MAC address from an IP address.

Comment: MAC is used in the data link layer, not the network layer, so I seriously doubt it.

Comment: @E.Moffat How it is possible to transform to C# code ?

Comment: @Amy Well... Would you mind to provide a proper way to get it by IP address and port, please?

Comment: @Dimi : You'd have to [Platform Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx) the IP helper methods. Examples can be found at http://pinvoke.net/, like this one: [GetExtendedTcpTable()](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi/GetExtendedTcpTable.html).

Comment: An IP/port is part of the network layer.  You can't.  That's the point.  The MAC is available only to immediately adjacent network nodes.  Past that point, it has no use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The MAC address is part of the [Link layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite#Link_layer), only used to communicate two hosts in the same physical link.

Oversimplifying..., imagine that `a` and `c` are computers, and `b` is a router.

```
a <-> b <-> c
```

If `a` wants to send a packet to `c`, it has to go through `b`. So `a` sends packet with source IP address `a`, target IP address `c`, source MAC address `a`  and target MAC address `b`, since the router is the next hop. Then when `b` gets that packet, it will send it to `c` using source IP address `a`, target IP address `c`, source MAC address `b` and target MAC address `c`.

Comment: Please, help to get some code to get MAC address via IP address then...

Comment: You cannot get the MAC address via IP. You can get the MAC addresses of the IP addresses you are directly connected for example using `arp -a <ip_address>'. And directly connected means via a hub or a basic switch.

Answer (score 7):

So the answer is no it is impossible.

But by IP address we can get MAC address like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication14
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("12.3.0.42");
            byte[] t = GetMacAddress(address);
            string mac = string.Join(":", (from z in t select z.ToString("X2")).ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(mac);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern int SendARP(uint destIP, uint srcIP, byte[] macAddress, ref uint macAddressLength);

        public static byte[] GetMacAddress(IPAddress address)
        {
            byte[] mac = new byte[6];
            uint len = (uint)mac.Length;
            byte[] addressBytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
            uint dest = ((uint)addressBytes[3] << 24)
              + ((uint)addressBytes[2] << 16)
              + ((uint)addressBytes[1] << 8)
              + ((uint)addressBytes[0]);
            if (SendARP(dest, 0, mac, ref len) != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("The ARP request failed.");
            }
            return mac;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thumbs up for solving the issue. The other answers expect that you wanted to do it across different networks, but in LAN it is possible, as you just proved. Thanks for posting the answer!