# How to find an extrernal device's MAC Address? How to find the MAC addresses of all the network computers?

Tags: c#, tcp, connection, tcpclient, mac-address

I want to search and find for specific devices in the local network and connect to them.

To verify that the computer that I connect to is the right one , I want to get first  the MAC addresses of all the computers in the network and then choose the connection that I want to make every time.

Could anyone help me with this issue?

So far I use C#  and TCP Clients Classes.

But I do not know how to find the MAC address of another computer , **not the one** that the application run  . 
I want to find the MAC address of the computer that I want to connect to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290861/get-mac-address-via-tcplistener-in-c-sharp

Comment: The MAC address is return as part of a PING (ARP Request/Response).  So from cmd.exe >PING IP then get arp table from cmd.exe >ARP -A  You can do same in c# code.

Comment: @jdweng  , could you please tell me how to do it in C# , because  I really do not know how to get the ARP table in C#  , in CMD I know , but in C#  I have never tried before

Comment: See Pinvoke : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.GetIpNetTable

Answer (score 0):

To solve a similar task I created a small MIT-licensed library called [ArpLookup](https://github.com/georg-jung/ArpLookup) ([nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArpLookup/)).

Features:

- works directly from C# without creating any `ping` or `arp` processes
- supports Windows and Linux
- provides an `Async` variant on Linux (it does on Windows too but it can not be truly async there)
- is free and open source

After `dotnet add package ArpLookup` usage works like this

```cs
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using ArpLookup;

// ...

PhysicalAddress mac = Arp.Lookup(IPAddress.Parse("1.2.3.4"));

PhysicalAddress mac = await Arp.LookupAsync(IPAddress.Parse("1.2.3.4"));
```